# pandas won't import despite trying many versions of python

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I just ran `python -m install pandas`, but I can't import pandas:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3978, in <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8891, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core import window as rwindow
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window as _window
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried various python versions(3.4, 3.5., 3.6, etc) and 32 vs 64 bit but with no luck. I'm running Python 3.6 on 32 bit now on windows.

I can see this file: `window.cp36-win32.pyd` inside the pandas _libs folder under my site-packages. What's wrong with it?

Comment: are you using version 0.23 of pandas? If so then try uninstalling it and installing v0.22 `pip install pandas==0.22`

Comment: @letroot - wow this actually did the trick. Would accept as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas v0.23 was released on May 15, 2018 and there are still some issues of which yours is one. Except you absolutely have to use 0.23, try installing v0.22
`pip install pandas==0.22`

More info here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21106